# Docker container w multiple processes (Tensorboard and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: docker, docker-container

I am trying to get tensor board an jupyter notebook to run in one container on two separate ports, `6006` and `8888`, while also including tensor flow and keras.

I've used this command:

```
docker rm -f keras; docker run --name keras -v DIR:/notebooks -p 8888:8888  -p 6006:6006 cannin/jupyter-keras-tensorflow-tools:tf-1.0.1
```

but I can only access the Jupyter notebook from `localhost:8888` and not tensor board through `localhost:6006`.

Comment: did you try query ports from container.  (docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash), and then wget or curl localhost 6006. maybe tensor  doesn't start.

Comment: "failed to connect to port 6006"

Comment: What is write in the logs?

Comment: I ran : mkdir tf_logs then: tensorboard --logdir tf_logs and got tensor board to run on port 6006 but is there any way to package tensor board in my docker run command so both Jupyter and Tensorboard are available from the docker run command?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand you, but You can run two commands in one RUN statement with " RUN aCommand &  bCommand"